# jQuery cubic terminal, to print result lines on console with html formats

Tags: jquery, jquery-terminal

i want somehow in  echo function to display html contents in  terminal

just simple hello to be bold in following example

```
    $("#tm").terminal(function (command, term) {
              term.echo('<b>Hello</b> '+command);
           }
```

I really don;t know how it is feasible, but there should be some option to assign it html contents in string.

Comment: Could you please rephrase this question as it's not clear what you're trying to do? Are you referring to the console?

Comment: Yes,  I just want to display result as HTML doc like table , URL links on console .  Let's say I can use same echo function with option html contents, so whatever html tags in string will be interpreted and display html on console.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo html if you specify option raw:

```
term.echo('<b>Hello</b> ' + command, {raw: true});
```

or if you only want to bold the text use terminal formatting:

```
term.echo('[[b;;]Hello] ' + command);
```